# Why are outgoing international wires from the United States typically more expensive than outgoing domestic wires?

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, fees, wire-transfer

I see on https://www.finder.com/bank-fees-wire-transfers ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20210118095845/https://www.finder.com/bank-fees-wire-transfers)) that outgoing international wires from the US are typically more expensive than outgoing domestic wires:

| Bank | Incoming domestic wire | Outgoing domestic wire | Incoming international wire | Outgoing international wire |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ally (online bank) | $0 | $20 | $0 | Not offered |
| Bank of America | $15 | $30 | $16 | $35–$45 |
| BB&T | $15 | $30 | $15 | $30 |
| Capital One 360 (online bank) | $0 | $30 | $0 | Not offered |
| Chase | $15 | $25–$35 | $15 | $40–$50 |
| Citibank | $15 | $10–$25 | $15 | $10–$35 |
| PNC Bank | $15 | $30 | $15 | $45 |
| TD Bank | $15 | $25 | $15 | $40 |
| US Bank | $20 | $30 | $25 | $50 |
| Wells Fargo | $15 | $30 | $16 | $45 |

Why are outgoing international wires from the US typically more expensive than outgoing domestic wires?

The same page mentions:

> Domestic vs. international. Because domestic wire transfers involve less processing, they tend to be cheaper than international wire transfers. International wire transfers typically involve multiple banking systems and operators between the two countries.

but I don't see why International wire transfers can't be done with the same banking system/operator such as SWIFT.

Comment: The short pseudo answer? Regulations, historical differences, different laws and differences in opinion. In the same vein as "Why isn't there a unified world government and people don't piss Goldschlager?".  Imagine that banks and groups of banks are a bunch of children in a room and there is no unified authority to force them to cooperate. There is a very small chance they might do so on their own, but a much bigger chance they will just form camps based on their individual circumstance and relationships with one another.

Comment: Indeed.  Pls see *"What will now inevitably happen on this QA"* on the answer below!

Answer (score 2):

If I sell you a house in Denver, it involves agents; if I sell you a house overseas you could say "oh it still just involves agents" but obviously there's more rigmarole - more agents, more transactions.

> International wire transfers typically involve multiple banking systems and operators between the two countries

The statement given on the "finder" site is clear as day and is as reasonable an explanation as is possible.

Note that

- there is a flood of recent questions "but *WHY* is there a difference in price between A and B bank transactions?"

There are two streams of thought:

- (A) **There is no real reason, there is only a rationale. Banks "get away with what they can". Their rationales are bullshit.**  (Inasmuch as the rationales are bullshit, they are completely obvious and need no discussion - less automation, more parties involved.)
- (B) **The operation is more complex so it costs more.** (Inasmuch as the operations are complex, they are completely obvious and need no discussion - less automation, more parties involved.)

Note that "A" is **trivially "proved" on the grandest scale**: in Europe the government said "all transactions will be 30 cents only" and "magically" this was achieved in one day (and the banks still make billions in fees).

Conversely "B" can trivially be "proved" by simply pointing out the (completely obvious, profoundly not worth discussing) system differences.

## The answer is either "A" or "B".

"Deciding" between A and B is essentially "political".

You might as well as, are Republicans or Democrats better, or, should Canada be partitioned. It's a completely pointless political-like debate.

**Honestly Franck you're not going to get any answer more than "A" or "B".**

We will now see a huge amount of discussion on the following themes! ...

## What will now inevitably happen on this QA:

- An endless detailed debate about the technical nature of these transactions (which is utterly pointless and irrelevant to the question. Whether you are in camp "A" or "B", the technical nature of these transactions means nothing in deciding on "A" or "B")
- An endless detailed debate on whether "politically" banks are bastards (so: A) or businesses like any other (so: B).  This is unanswerable and the details of the debate are pointless here.
- Folks pointlessly explaining the details of how to do a wire transfer, because, they did one once in 1998 :O
- Folks from Europe endlessly pointing out that the US banking system is psychotic and the US doesn't even have pin codes on credit cards (newsflash: this is known)
- Endless bitchy bickering between people who work in the business about who has the most insider knowledge, which is pointless as any amount of technical knowledge has no bearing on "A" or "B" ... which again, is an unanswerable debate.

Finally I would note that...

## At worst, these "but why?" questions are just agitprop.

If I post on the travel site "*why* is bread so bad in the US" all I'm really doing is using a forum to whine, but I'm **covering it as a sort of pseudo-scientific question**. (This happens on the politics SE site constantly and is a huge PITA.)

Nobody can answer deep epistemological "but why" questions; why is the S&P so strong, why is real estate flat in Tasmania, why are tax rates low in Andorra - who the hell knows?

Comment: This. I find "why" questions are almost always off topic at best.  Couldn't have said it all better myself.

Comment: I said it to save us all typing .... to procrastinate from work !  :O